# Delete object after using it in function C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a question about **delete** and **memory leak** in C++. Considered the code below:

```
class AnObject{
public:
    AnObject* Foo(){
        // how can I delete this object ???
        AnObject* obj = new AnObject();
        ...
        return obj;
    }
};

int main(){
    ...
    AnObject* x = new AnObject();
    AnObject* result = x->Foo();

    delete x;

    return 0;
}
```

My question is how can I delete the pointer in fuction AnObject::Foo() ???

// I read some suggestions who required changing the function, don't create an object with the word **new** in a fucntion. But does it exist a method to delete this pointer ?

Comment: You can't; the caller has to. Raw pointers don't manage themselves. Return something that portrays ownership and will clean itself up.

Comment: You delete just the same way as later on: "delete obj;"

Comment: You shouldn't delete the object inside the function as it makes the returned pointer invalid. The owner (`main` in your case) should destroy it: `delete result;`.

Comment: No Matthias, the problem is where I put "delete" ? I need an object as result of function Foo(). Outside of Foo(), the pointer is released but the memory of object isn't deleted, it provoke memory leak.

Comment: The problem here isn't really how to delete the object, it's who owns it.  This is a problem I encounter all the time developing APIs.  Smart pointers are a partial solution (weak_ptr can be converted to shared_ptr so it's not guaranteed).  unique_ptr if you own it of course but before you decide on how to code it, you need to be clear about ownership through the object's lifetime.

Comment: @Amateur I do not really understand this comment: "Outside of Foo(), the pointer is released but the memory of object isn't deleted". Afaik, the code you show is perfectly fine, you create via `new` and delete via `delete`, there is no memory leak in this case.

Comment: ..ups I didnt read the snippet carefully enough. I thought you delete the returned object in the main. However, I would still think that once you put a `delete result;` at the end of your main, them there is no memory leak.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would do so by deleting `this` within `AnObject::Foo` but I would strongly discourage you from doing so. In this case, you do not need pointers at all:

```
class AnObject{
public:
    AnObject Foo(){
        return AnObject{};
    }
};

int main()
{
    AnObject x{};
    AnObject result = x.Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

If for whatever reason you really do need pointers, consider smart pointers

```
#include <memory>
class AnObject{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<AnObject> Foo(){
        return std::make_unique<AnObject>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<AnObject> x = std::make_unique<AnObject>();
    std::unique_ptr<AnObject> result = x->Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

In both cases, you do not need to `delete` anything as you are using RAII semantics to handle your memory cleanup via scope.

Comment: Hi Cory, using smart pointer, I have to change the type return of function to type of smart pointer too ?

Comment: @Amateur Of course. The client calling your function has to use the same semantics too, otherwise all your efforts are lost as soon as you leave the function.

Optimally, *all* your code that contain owning pointers (pointers that you have to call delete on) should be changed to std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr, whether is it a return type, a member variable, a local variable or a function argument

Comment: @Amateur, Yes, and then the caller knows exactly what they can do with the returned value, as opposed to guessing with a regular pointer (unless you have some convention that all raw pointers do not own anything).

Comment: @all, brief, I need change the type return of all functions (who return object) to smart pointers ?

Comment: @Amateur Do not worry about functions returning an object (allocated on the stack). And as he mentioned, it is much easier to avoid pointers whenever possible instead of having to worry about objects lifetimes (even if one can use smart pointers to make it a bit less troublesome).